# Diagonalization without computing the inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse, diagonalization

Is there a way to find `A = PDP^-1` but without computing the inverse of P?

If `PP^-1`equal to identity matrix, can I say `A = ID` ?

Comment: It will **always** be true that $\;PP^{-1}=I\;$ , so that should be a hint for you that no: you can't definitely say $\;A=I\;$ as matrix multiplication isn't, in general, commutative. You can diagonalize $\;A\;$ though if it is diagonalizable and if you know the matrix's eigenvalues, without any need of $\;P\;$ or of its inverse.

Comment: Given a diagonalizable matrix $A$, it is possible to compute both $P$ and $D$ without computing $P^{-1}$.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. Now I understand after DonAntonio's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the normalised eigenvectors of your matrix and make these eigenvectors the columns of a new matrix U.
Now calculate U^T * P * U using matrix multiplication and then you will obtain a diagonalised matrix with the eigenvalues of P as the entries on the diagonal.

NB: U^T is U-transpose.

Comment: No need to normalize eigenvectors,  but much more important:  in general,  multiplying by the traspose won't diagonalize a matrix **even** if its diagonalizable, so the above is incorrect.